# How to make my Neural Netwok run on GPU instead of CPU

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I have installed Anaconda3 and have installed latest versions of Keras and Tensorflow.

Running this command :

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

I find the Notebook is running in CPU:

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 2888773992010593937
]

This is my Nvidia version:

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:04_Central_Daylight_Time_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

running nvidia-smi, I'm getting this result:
[image]

I want to make the neural network to train on GPU. Please help me in switching from CPU to GPU.

Comment: I have the same problem, I run the simple script given by "n1k31t4" as above, and the output are: > Input shape: (50, 50) using Device: cpu took: 3.44 > Input shape: (100,100) using Device: cpu took: 3.47 > Input shape: (500, 500) using Device: cpu took: 3.56 > Input shape: (1000, 1000) using Device: cpu took: 3.36 My PC has AMD FX-8350 CPU and GeForce GTX 1050Ti graphics card.
I used the command "conda create --name tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu" to install TF on my Windows 10 Pro PC.
conda list output the following: cudatoolkit 9.0 1 cudnn 7.1.4 cuda9.0_0 tensorflow 1.12.0 gpu_py36ha5f9131_0 tensorf

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First some stupid sanity-check questions: do you have a GPU in your local machine? (you didn't mention that explicitly). I ask because it will not work e.g. on an integrated Intel graphics card found in some laptops.

Second, you installed Keras and Tensorflow, but did you install the GPU version of Tensorflow? [Using Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu), this would be done with the command:

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

Other useful things to know:

- what operating system are you using? (I assume Linux e.g. Ubuntu)
- what GPU do you expect to be shown as available?
- Can you run the command: `nvidia-smi` in a terminal and update your question with the output?

If you have installed the correct package (the above method is one of a few possible ways of doing it), and if you have an Nvidia-GPU available, Tensorflow would usually by default reserve all available memory of the GPU as soon as it starts building the static graph.

---

If you were not already, it is probably a good idea to use a conda environment, which keeps the requirements of your model separate from whatever your system might already have installed. [**Have a look at this nice little walkthrough on getting started**](https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-gpu-installation-made-easy-use-conda-instead-of-pip-52e5249374bc) - this will likely be a good test to see if your system is able to run models on a GPU as it removes all other possible problems created components unrelated to your script. In short, create and activate a new envrinment that includes the GPU version of Tensowflow like this:

```
conda create --name gpu_test tensorflow-gpu    # creates the env and installs tf
conda activate gpu_test                        # activate the env
python test_gpu_script.py                      # run the script given below
```

---

### UPDATE

I would suggest running a small script to execute a few operations in Tensorflow on a CPU and on a GPU. This will rule out the problem that you might not have enough memory for the RNN you're trying to train.

I made a script to do that, so it tests the same operations on a CPU and GPU and prints a summary. You should be able to just copy-paste the code and run it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

# Choose which device you want to test on: either 'cpu' or 'gpu'
devices = ['cpu', 'gpu']

# Choose size of the matrix to be used.
# Make it bigger to see bigger benefits of parallel computation
shapes = [(50, 50), (100, 100), (500, 500), (1000, 1000)]


def compute_operations(device, shape):
    """Run a simple set of operations on a matrix of given shape on given device

    Parameters
    ----------
    device : the type of device to use, either 'cpu' or 'gpu' 
    shape : a tuple for the shape of a 2d tensor, e.g. (10, 10)

    Returns
    -------
    out : results of the operations as the time taken
    """

    # Define operations to be computed on selected device
    with tf.device(device):
        random_matrix = tf.random_uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1)
        dot_operation = tf.matmul(random_matrix, tf.transpose(random_matrix))
        sum_operation = tf.reduce_sum(dot_operation)

    # Time the actual runtime of the operations
    start_time = datetime.now()
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as session:
            result = session.run(sum_operation)
    elapsed_time = datetime.now() - start_time

    return result, elapsed_time



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Run the computations and print summary of each run
    for device in devices:
        print("--" * 20)

        for shape in shapes:
            _, time_taken = compute_operations(device, shape)

            # Print the result and also the time taken on the selected device
            print("Input shape:", shape, "using Device:", device, "took: {:.2f}".format(time_taken.seconds + time_taken.microseconds/1e6))
            #print("Computation on shape:", shape, "using Device:", device, "took:")

    print("--" * 20)
```

#### Results from running on CPU:

```
Computation on shape: (50, 50),       using Device: 'cpu' took: 0.04s
Computation on shape: (500, 500),     using Device: 'cpu' took: 0.05s
Computation on shape: (1000, 1000),   using Device: 'cpu' took: 0.09s
Computation on shape: (10000, 10000), using Device: 'cpu' took: 32.81s
```

#### Results from running on GPU:

```
Computation on shape: (50, 50),       using Device: 'gpu' took: 0.03s
Computation on shape: (500, 500),     using Device: 'gpu' took: 0.04s
Computation on shape: (1000, 1000),   using Device: 'gpu' took: 0.04s
Computation on shape: (10000, 10000), using Device: 'gpu' took: 0.05s
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm having a Nvidia GTX1060 GPU.

Comment: I tried running the given coda command in prompt. I use a MSI laptop which has the Msi centre that displays the CPU and GPU consumption. When I train my Neural netwok I don find the GPU being consumed even after running the given command.

Comment: It seems like your Python interpreter is just not able to see the GPU. This might be a permissions issue or Windows related, as I haven't ever had this problem on Linux. If following that linked tutorial doesn't fix the problem, I am afraid I don't know a solution. My only final thought would be that the model you are training doesn't actually use the GPU. Could you share a minimal example of a model with the training code, which still doesn't use the GPU?

Comment: I'm trying to run a simple RNN program. Now, after following few prior steps I'm get 'GPU Sync failed' error. Which I presume that the GPU is used but it has some issues in capacity.

Comment: @DeniAvinash - please try using my update to confirm your GPU is working.

Comment: Hi, Looks like my Code runs on GPU as well. Thanks for the sharing the code. I also ran a normal ANN today and I found that it consumed GPU. Looks like the RNN code I had was too much for the GPU. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: @n1k31t4, thanks for your classic contribution. However, trying to run your scripts on the latest tensorflow(gpu) is giving me error: RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run(). Kindly show me the modifications I need to make.